How to solve the infeasibility problem I receive in a very simple SDDP.jl model
I am experimenting with SDDP.jl to develop a multistage stochastic capacity expansion model for district heating. I have started working with a very simple model but receiving an infeasibility problem I couldn't solve yet. Below is the Julia code I use and receive the infeasibility error:
using SDDP, GLPK

# Problem Data
T = 3  # Total number of years
initial_capacity = 80
# demand = [80, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0, 200.0]
demand = [80, 120.0, 150.0]
expansion_cost = 50.0
operational_cost = 3.0
max_additional_capacity = 50.0

# SDDP Model
model = SDDP.LinearPolicyGraph(;
    stages=T,
    sense=:Min,
    lower_bound=0.0,
    optimizer=GLPK.Optimizer,
) do sp, t
    # State variables
    @variable(sp, 0.0 <= capacity <= 500.0, SDDP.State, initial_value = initial_capacity)
    # Control variables
    @variable(sp, 0.0 <= expansion <= max_additional_capacity)
    @variable(sp, production >= 0.0)
    # Constraints
    @constraint(sp, capacity.out == capacity.in + expansion)
    @constraint(sp, production == demand[t])
    @constraint(sp, production <= capacity.in)  # Production constrained by available capacity
    # Stage-objective
    @stageobjective(sp, operational_cost * production + expansion_cost * expansion)
end

# Solve the model
SDDP.train(model, iteration_limit=1000)

I have tried commenting out constraints and the last constraint is causing the issue. I have the feeling that something is not correct with the state variable "capacity" being transferred within the nodes, but I couldn't solve it.

I actually found a relevant example in SDDP.jl documentation: https://sddp.dev/stable/guides/access_previous_variables/
However, I still do not understand why I cannot model the capacities as I did in the question posted. In the link I share, the capacity is zero in the first stage, so it requires a constraint free model in the first stage. But, in my example, I want to start with an existing capacity and keep building on it.

So, after reading through the manuals again and rechecking the examples, it turned out that I was violating the "relatively complete recourse" requirement. For instance, in the first period, having no expansion is a feasible decision at this stage. However, it creates infeasibility since the available capacity will not be enough to meet the demand in the next stage.
I solved the issue by presenting an unmet demand variable with a penalty inspired by this example: https://sddp.dev/stable/examples/generation_expansion/ Warning: if you implement a penalty cost with a similar scale to the one in the example (5e5), it creates a numerical stability issue. Therefore, I introduced a penalty cost slightly higher than the unit expansion cost.
Below is the final code:
using SDDP, GLPK

# Problem Data
T = 5  # Total number of years
initial_capacity = 80
demand = [80, 120, 150, 180, 200]
expansion_cost = 50
operational_cost = 3
max_additional_capacity = 50
# Cost of unmet demand
penalty = 60

# SDDP Model
model = SDDP.LinearPolicyGraph(;
    stages=T,
    sense=:Min,
    lower_bound=0,
    optimizer=GLPK.Optimizer,
) do sp, t
    # State variables
    @variable(sp, 0 <= capacity <= 500, SDDP.State, initial_value = initial_capacity)
    # Control variables
    #@variable(sp, 0.0 <= expansion <= max_additional_capacity)
    @variable(sp, expansion >= 0)
    @variable(sp, production >= 0)
    @variable(sp, unmet >= 0)
    # Constraints
    @constraint(sp, capacity.out == capacity.in + expansion)
    #@constraint(sp, production == demand[t])
    @constraint(sp, production + unmet == demand[t])
    # allow unmet demand with a penalty to ensure relatively complete recourse
    @constraint(sp, production <= capacity.in)  # Production constrained by available capacity
    # Stage-objective
    @stageobjective(sp, operational_cost * production + expansion_cost * expansion + unmet * penalty)
end

# Solve the model
SDDP.train(model, iteration_limit=100)

# Retrieve results
println("Optimal Cost: ", SDDP.calculate_bound(model))

# Simulation
simulations = SDDP.simulate(model, 1, [:capacity, :production, :expansion])
for t in 1:T
    sp = simulations[1][t]
    println("Year $t: Capacity_in = ", value(sp[:capacity].in), ", Expansion = ", value(sp[:expansion]),
        ", Capacity_out = ", value(sp[:capacity].out), ", Production = ", value(sp[:production]))
end

